# Knockoutjs attr with click

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to attach a click event to my template inside a for each loop. My template looks like this.

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="foreach: socialData">
            <div class="col-md-12 horizontal-padding lib-item" data-category="view">
                <div class="lib-panel">
                    <div class="row box-shadow">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty("media_url") -->
                            <img class="lib-img-show" data-bind="attr: { src: media_url }">
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="lib-row lib-header">
                                <span>
                                <span data-bind="text: full_name"></span>
                                (<span data-bind="text: user_name"></span>)
                                <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty("user_image") -->
                                <img class="pull-right img-circle thumbnail" data-bind="attr: { src: user_image }">
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                </span>
                                <div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lib-row lib-desc">
                                <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
                                <div class="lib-header-seperator"></div>
                                <hr/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning feature"
                                        data-bind="attr: { id: feature_id }">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Feature
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                        data-bind="attr: { id: block_id }, click: blockItem">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>Block
                                </button>
                                <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty("media_url") -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary download"
                                        data-bind="attr: { id: download_id }">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>Download
                                </button>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my view code and the ajax call.

```
var targeturl = "/ajax/{{ event_id }}/";
        var page = "0";

        $(function () {
            function fetch_data() {
                $.getJSON(targeturl + page, function (data) {
                    // add block, feature and download ids
                    data1.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.block_id = "block-" + item._id;
                        item.feature_id = "feature-" + item._id;
                        item.download_id = "download-" + item._id;
                    });

                    var viewModel = {
                        socialData: ko.observableArray(data1),
                        blockItem: function(item) {
                            console.log(item);
                        }
                    };
                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert('error');
                });
            }


            // start function
            fetch_data();
        });
```

When, I add `click` to the `data-bind` knockout is throwing an error:

> ReferenceError: blockItem is not defined

How do I append a click event in the array item.

Comment: I am getting "ReferenceError: blockItem is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the function exists at a higher level than the currently bound item from the array - it's looking for `blockItem` on each individual item.  Instead, you can tell it to look in the parent context so it finds it on your viewmodel:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
    data-bind="attr: { id: block_id }, click: $parent.blockItem">
```